# What kind of debit or credit cards issued in the US work to withdraw cash at the ATMs located at Hakodate airport?

Tags: airports, japan, hokkaido

What kind of debit or credit cards issued in the US work to withdraw cash (yen) at the ATMs located at Hakodate airport (HKD)?

I tried one debit card from Bank of America as well 4 credit cards from Bank of America and Amazon prime, none them worked with the two English-speaking ATMs I could find at the Hakodate airport in the domestic terminal. I'm only interested in credit and debit cards issued in the United States.

The first ATM was AEON. The second ATM gave this receipt (from which you can read the ATM name if you can't read Japanese):

[image]

[image]

---

There is a cash exchange machine (https://smartexchange.jp/all/) in the international terminal of the airport. It can exchange the most common currencies into yen, but the exchange rate is bad, e.g. approximately 7% over the market rate to exchange USD into yen.

Comment: How were these two ATMs branded?

Comment: @jpatokal see question edit, I'm hoping to be able to upload the image within 48 hours.

Comment: The second ATM is from Hokkaido Bank (北海道銀行); ATMs of regional banks rarely (never?) take foreign cards. The Aeon one [supposedly does](https://map.aeonbank.co.jp/aeonbank/spot/detail?code=0000005170&lang=en), but those things are very hit-and-miss.

Comment: @fkraiem thanks for the information. Any idea what factor can make it a hit?

Comment: Sadly no, it seems almost random... US cards do seem to be more often problematic than, say, European ones, however.

Comment: Stupid question but there were no card companies logo (Visa, MasterCard,...) on the ATM?

Comment: @fkraiem Purely anecdotal, but some widely-available datasets used to train Machine Learning systems about credit card fraud show that a leading indicator of fraud is US nationality with age under mid-twenties..

Comment: One of the sentences on the ATM slip translates to: Cannot read the card's magnetic data.

Comment: @Taladris visa and MasterCard logos were both present on the ATM

Comment: @mkennedy thanks for the translation. I should add that I got the same error message for all the five cards I tried.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: so that seems to answer (partially) the question. I have never been to Hakodate airport but, in my experience in Japan (8 visits, in Tokyo, Osaka, Fukushima, Okinawa, Tsushima,...), I have never had any problem with a Mastercard with ATMs that displayed the logo. The problem is to find an ATM that displays the Mastercard logo. They are not that common, even in large, touristy, commercial areas. It seems that post offices usually accept Mastercards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems other users are experiencing similar issues as seen [here](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g298143-i5078-k7611588-Foreign_ATM_card_warning-Hokkaido.html).

You can either:

- Bring cash to exchange
- Use an international ATM:

Note these aren’t located at the airport. The two international ATMs are [Sevenbank](https://www.sevenbank.co.jp/intlcard/index2.html) which accepts cards including AMEX and visa, and [Japan Post Bank](https://www.jp-bank.japanpost.jp/en/ias/en_ias_index.html) which also accepts international cards. (Not affiliated with these services)

These two ATMs were found on [this tourist](https://www.hakodate.travel/en/information/exchange) website.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Note that there is a cash exchange at the airport, I will add this information in the question.